# How can I specialize a method for a specific generic type?

Tags: rust

I want to define methods for `Untyped` and `Unit` or basically every type, but I want to specialize a few methods just for `Unit`.

The problem is that Rust doesn't allow two implementations here. I am using Rust 1.9, do I need to enable specialzation or is this just not possible?

```
use num::Float; // 0.2.1
use std::marker::PhantomData;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Untyped;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Unit;

struct Vector<T, Type> {
    data: [T; 3],
    _m: PhantomData<Type>,
}

impl<T> Vector<T, Unit>
where
    T: Float,
{
    fn length(&self) -> T {
        println!("SPECIAL");
        T::one()
    }
}

impl<T, Type> Vector<T, Type>
where
    T: Float,
{
    fn length(&self) -> T {
        println!("NON SPECIAL");
        T::one()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = Vector::<f32, Untyped> {
        data: [1., 2., 3.],
        _m: PhantomData,
    };
    let v1 = Vector::<f32, Unit> {
        data: [1., 2., 3.],
        _m: PhantomData,
    };
    let l = v.length();
    let l1 = v1.length();
}
```

```
error[E0592]: duplicate definitions with name `length`
  --> src/main.rs:19:5
   |
19 | /     fn length(&self) -> T {
20 | |         println!("SPECIAL");
21 | |         T::one()
22 | |     }
   | |_____^ duplicate definitions for `length`
...
29 | /     fn length(&self) -> T {
30 | |         println!("NON SPECIAL");
31 | |         T::one()
32 | |     }
   | |_____- other definition for `length`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to specialize a method defined in an inherent `impl`, rather than specializing a method defined in a trait. This appears to not be supported at the moment, even after adding `default` to the "non special" `length` method. [RFC 1210](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md) mentions inherent `impl`s as a possible extension, which I understand as not being considered for implementation at the moment.

As a workaround, consider moving your method to a trait. This requires specialization to be enabled to work, so you'll need to use a nightly compiler until the feature is stabilized.

Instead of defining the default implementation on the trait, we define it in the general `impl`. We need to add the `default` contextual keyword to that function.

```
#![feature(specialization)]

trait VectorExt<T>
where
    T: Float,
{
    fn length(&self) -> T;
}

impl<T, Type> VectorExt<T> for Vector<T, Type>
where
    T: Float,
{
    default fn length(&self) -> T {
        println!("NON SPECIAL");
        T::one()
    }
}

impl<T> VectorExt<T> for Vector<T, Unit>
where
    T: Float,
{
    fn length(&self) -> T {
        println!("SPECIAL");
        T::one()
    }
}

// This `impl` is not strictly necessary,
// but it will let users of your type
// use the `length` method
// without having to `use` the `VectorExt` trait.
impl<T, Type> Vector<T, Type>
where
    T: Float,
{
    fn length(&self) -> T
    where
        Self: VectorExt<T>,
    {
        VectorExt::<T>::length(self)
        // can also be written as: <Self as VectorExt<T>>::length(self)
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=da0dbf4dcecfc5bfa64f24499bcf851b)